# rails_admin and devise Running a method on new user creation and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I'm trying to introduce a method into my rails app that will take values entered into the rails_admin new user form and pass a method to populate the remaining, read-only parts of the user. The user model is a devise model.

I've tried introducing the method in a custom devise controller using `if save` but inspecting the console, the method did not seem to run.

I imagine this would require a config of the edit action in rails admin, but I am unsure how to self-reference with rails admin and how to call `if save` in this instance.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: post some code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what code I would even post. I am not receiving an error. I'm more just trying to figure out if there is a way to write a method into the save action for rails-admin. If there is a relevant section of code you would suggest I would be happy to post what I've got

Comment: Try posting your form code and the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood your question well, but you want a method to be called after the user saves an object right? I've done this in the past:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :downtimes

  # A getter used to populate the field on rails admin
  def downtime_reason
    downtimes.last.reason
  end

  # A setter that will be called with whatever the user wrote in your field
  def downtime_reason=(reason)
    downtimes.find_or_create_by(reason: reason)
  end

  rails_admin do
    configure :downtime_reason, :text do
      virtual? 
    end

    edit do
      field :downtime_reason
    end
  end
end
```

I would not advise to mess with rails admin controllers. But if you must and you want to change the parameters on post you can always do:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :modify_params if: :in_admin_controller?

  def modify_params
    params[:something] = 'your brand new value'
  end

  def in_admin_controller?
    params[:controller] == 'rails_admin/main'
  end
end
```

This depends on rails admin controller inheriting from the application controller, in the latest(1.2.0) rails admin this can be configure in an initializer like so:

```
#/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'
end
```